# Ruby on Rails: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue with my `add_item` method and have trouble to understand why.

Here is my `carts_controller.rb`

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cart_items = CartItem.all
  end

  def add_item
    @cart_item = CartItem.new
    produit_id = params[:produit_id]
    @cart_item = CartItem.find_or_create_by(params[:produit][:produit_id])
    @cart_item.save

    binding.pry
  end
end
```

Here is `produits/index.html.erb` (where the issue comes from)

```
<div id="produits-column-container">
  <% if @produits %>
    <% @produits.in_groups_of(4, false).each do |g| %>
      <% g.each do |produit| %>
      <div id="produits-row-container">
        <div id="fiche-produit-container">
            <div id="produit-img">
              <%= image_tag produit.photo %>
            </div>
            <div id="produit-nom">
              <%= produit.nom %>
            </div>
            <div id="produit-prix">
              <%= number_to_currency(produit.prix, unit: '€', format: "%n%u") %>
            </div>
            <div id="produit-au-panier">
              <%= image_tag('icon/icon-panier') %>
              <%= link_to 'Ajouter au panier', carts_add_item_path, method: :post %>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The error i'm given is :

```
ArgumentError in CartsController#add_item
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

in def add_item(produit_id)
```

`add_item(produit_id)` is related to `carts_add_item_path`

I also give you the routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  match "/mon-panier" => 'carts#index', via: :get

  post 'carts/add_item' => 'carts#add_item'

  resources :categories do
    resources :produits
  end

  resources :order_abonnements, only: [:create, :update, :delete]

  get 'livraisons_type/index'

  match "/recapitulatif" => 'recapitulatif#index', via: :get

  match "/confirmation-carte-cadeau" => 'recapitulatif#confirmation', via: :get

  match "/livraison-carte-cadeau" => 'livraison_carte#index', via: :get

  match '/activation-carte' => 'code_carte_cadeau#index', via: :get

  match "/offrir-une-box-bretonne" => 'cadeau#index', via: :get

  resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

  match "/nos-box" => 'nos_box#index', via: :get

  get 'categories/index'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  match '/informations-penn-ar-box' => 'informations_penn_ar_box#index', via: :get

  match '/livraison-box-bretonne' => 'livraison_box_bretonne#index', via: :get

  match '/abonnements' => 'abonnements#index', via: :get

  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'connexion', sign_out: 'déconnexion'}

  resources :users do
    delete 'déconnexion' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  match '/mon-marche-breton' => 'marche_breton#index', via: :get

  root 'home#home'
end
```

And the logs :

```
Started POST "/carts/add_item" for ::1 at 2017-05-30 09:48:52 +0200
Processing by CartsController#add_item as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"QrToQUHVxjuV5cUvZYHd7tj457htfZohOkmsvNDnKv79P413xjsSfR/8RVXtdIU7/wcmhcxjkU85N13CqJkG2w=="}
  Cart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 14.9ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
  app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:6:in `add_item'
```

Comment: Controller actions are not your ordinary ruby methods and they don't accept parameters like that, in the signature. You're supposed to read `params[:produit_id]` in the method body.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well, controller actions _are ordinary ruby methods_ after all, they just are called by the engine in some ways that the engine wants to call them.

Comment: @mudasobwa: you know what I meant. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what do i need to write to fix the issue? i'm in a hurry :)

Comment: @justinedps26: the answer is in the last sentence of my comment

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i did write your way but nothing changed

Comment: @justinedps26 you forgot to remove the parameter from the signature?

Comment: @justinedps26: `def add_item(produit_id)` should be `def add_item`

Comment: @justinedps26 as @SergioTulentsev explained, controller actions don't receive parameters; as you can see you even don't use such parameter in action body but you access to `params`. So just remove parameter from method signature and bug will be solved !

Comment: @SergioTulentsev now i have `undefined local variable or method `cart_items'`

Comment: @justinedps26: well, that's another issue, which doesn't have anything to do with the original error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well, i'll try to figure it out. Thanks for your help

Comment: Now the question is wrong. The code given can't produce stated error. And, as a general rule, you must not edit questions like that (so that it becomes another question entirely). This invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev okay sorry, i just did that to be more clear in the comments

Comment: @justinedps26: no problem. But do keep that in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145428/discussion-between-justinedps26-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass produit_id as a parameter.

So change this line as so...

```
<%= link_to 'Ajouter au panier', 
            carts_add_item_path(produit_id: produit.id), method: :post %>
```

And change your controller method as so...

```
def add_item
  produit_id = params[:produit_id]
  ...
```

And change the find_or_create to

```
@cart_item = CartItem.find_or_create_by(produit_id: produit_id)
```

This does mean that you can only have one CartItem in your entire application that points to a product... strange design.

Comment: That'll be useful, yes, but it's not the cause of the exact problem in the question.

Comment: ? @SergioTulentsev surely it is?  He's `calling carts_add_item_path` which resolves into a call to `add_item` without arguments. HIs definition of the `add_item` action expects an argument. *Wrong number of arguments, given 0, expected 1*.

Comment: No, invocation of `carts_add_item_path` does not end up with a call to `add_item`.

Comment: Ah, I see where I could be misunderstood. I was referring to the first part of the answer, the one with `carts_add_item_path(produit_id: produit.id)`. If you do only that (pass parameter this way) __and__ leave the action signature intact, you'll still see the error.

Comment: (_took the liberty to format some code. Horizontal scrolling on one-line snippets is horrible_)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the error went away but i now have `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: That's on line 7?  Did you spell "params" correctly?

Comment: I just realised you're not even using the argument!  Just remove it from the `def add_item` line.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, my answer was to do both steps, I wasn't giving OP a choice.  Good improvement on the formatting, I'll remember that for future.

Comment: And which line is the error?  Does it say `app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:8:in add_item` or `app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:9:in add_item' ?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn it says `app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:9:in `add_item' `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145427/discussion-between-justinedps26-and-steveturczyn).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that are wrong with this code, but the simplest thing you could do in order to suppress the error is to change the method signature to:

```
def add_item
```

instead of

```
def add_item(produit_id)
```

P.S. The controller is not [RESTful](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284). It's called `CartsController`, but in your index action you list the `CartItems`, not the `Carts`. The correct name should be `CartItemsController`. If you rename the controller to `CartItemsController`, than the `index` action can stay the same, but the `add_item` action should better be renamed to simply `create`. Thus, in your routes you can have:

```
resources :cart_items, only: [:index, :create]
```

Also, I am not exactly sure, what is going on in the `add_item` method - at first you assign a new `CartItem` to @cart_item, but then you override this assignment with `find_or_create_by...`. Also, the call to `save` at the end of the method is redundant, as `create` will save the record and otherwise no modifications have been made between the `find_or_create_by` line and the `save` line.

Comment: Thanks, can you let me know the other things that are wrong please?